# .htaccess use parameter from request_uri and query_string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I try to get call a page with this structure:

```
/page/my-selection.html?p=1
/page/my-selection2.html?p=3
/page/my-selection3.html?p=6
```

where my-selection, my-selection2, ... is a database key and p the pagination.
I want to redirect this on one single page, which does all the magic, but how i can use mod_rewrite to use the variables from both RewriteCond's?

I tried it this way, bit it doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} page/(.*)\.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=(.*)
RewriteRule page/(.*)\.html$ /rewrites/page.php?selection=$1&pagination=$2 [NC]
```

Examples:

- /page/my-selection.html?p=1 should redirect to
  /rewrites/page.php?selection=my-selection&pagination=1
- /page/my-selection2.html?p=3 should redirect to
  /rewrites/page.php?selection=my-selection2&pagination=3
- /page/my-selection3.html?p=6 should redirect to
  /rewrites/page.php?selection=my-selection3&pagination=6

Any Ideas?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=(.*)
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)\.html$ /rewrites/page.php?selection=$1&pagination=%1 [NC,L]
```

> **RewriteRule backreferences**: These are backreferences of the form $N
>   (0 <= N <= 9), which provide access to the grouped parts (in
>   parentheses) of the pattern, from the RewriteRule which is subject to
>   the current set of RewriteCond conditions..
>   **RewriteCond backreferences**: These are backreferences of the form %N (1 <= N <= 9),
>   which provide access to the grouped parts (again, in parentheses) of
>   the pattern, from the last matched RewriteCond in the current set of
>   conditions.
>   http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond