# Rewrite Pretty or SEO friendly URL via htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a problem with transforming urls from dynamic to static.

I have a site where different pages are generated with a dynamic url, like:

```
www.example.com/?pr=project-abc123
```

I would like to rewrite the url of each one with htaccess making it static, like this:

```
www.example.com/project-abc123

// or

www.example.com/pr/project-abc123
```

Now, i found this htaccess code that seems to work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/%1? [L,R=301] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index/?pr=$1[L]
```

URLs are rewritten as indicated (first type, whitout /pr/ ), but gives me a **multiple choice** error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Comment: See this one is well https://stackoverflow.com/a/36590510/12232340

Comment: `"multiple choice" error` - ? Presumably you have already changed the URLs in your application?

Comment: Nothing of this. The methods in the other topics don't work.  the message is: '300 Multiple choice. The document name you requested (/.php) could not be found on this server. However, we found documents with names similar to the one you requested.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's understand `RewriteRule` directive which is the real rewriting workhorse.

A `RewriteRule` consists of three arguments separated by spaces. The arguments are

- Pattern: which incoming URLs should be affected by the rule;
- Substitution: where should the matching requests be sent;
- [flags]: options affecting the rewritten request.

Let's start with the following snippet:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

First line of code, describes `RewriteEngine` is turned on. Here I use `RewriteCond` directive which defines a rewrite rule condition. Using `RewriteCond` directive we defined two conditions here. This directive took a server variable called `REQUEST_FILENAME`. The two conditions above tell if the request is not a file or a directory, then meet the rule set by `RewriteRule`. See [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41580649/7935051) on this issue.

Now it's time to write some rewrite rules. Let's convert

```
www.example.com/?pr=project-abc123

// to 

www.example.com/project-abc123
```

and rewrite rule will be:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?pr=$1 [L]
```

And to get the `www.example.com/pr/project-abc123` we need the rule as the below:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)/(.*)$ index.php/?$1=$2 [L]

// or

RewriteRule ^/?pr/(.*)$ index.php/?pr=$1 [L]
```

The [L] flag tells mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. This means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed.

Comment: Well, It works fine in my end. Did you check your mod_rewrite is enabled? Which version of apache are you using? Is your `MultiViews` enabled? If so, disable it like `Options -MultiViews`.

Comment: I did it. thank you.
The problem was htaccess instructions that conflict with these. 'MultiViews' is important?

Comment: Yes it is when content negotiation is important. Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25423722/7935051